# failed to create cluster: failed to init node with kubeadm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kind

I am fairly new to Kubernetes and I am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster on  ec2 Ubuntu machine using kind but it gives me a docker error[image: I am using kubernetes version 1.21]

Comment: Could you share your kind-cluster-config? Try with sudo?

Comment: I have tried with sudo but it gives the same result

here is the cluster config:
`kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
  - role: worker`

Comment: Have you tried to run the command that fails? (docker exec --privileged ...). Might tell you what's going on. What versions of docker do you have here?